# find time domain sequences using DTFT definition (NOT IDTFT)

Tags: matlab, dtft

The sequence is X(e^jw) = 3 + 2cos(w) + 4cos(2w), and the problem asks to use the definition of the DTFT to find the corresponding sequence.

I have tried using the IDTFT and integrating, but I could only find the first term which is a 3*delta function.

The book specifically wants you to use the DTFT definition, so I thought maybe I could just divide each term by e^-jwn?

could anyone please give some guidance? I am also trying to check my answer with MATLAB. thanks.

MATLAB code:

```
k = -500:500;
w = k*pi/max(k);

xn0 = 3;
xn1 = 2*cos(w)/exp(-j*w);
xn2 = 4*cos(2*w)/exp(-j*w*2);

n = 0:9;
x = [xn0 xn1 xn2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

stem(n,x);


X = dtft(n,x,k);
figure; plot(w/pi,abs(X));

X_check = 3 + 2*cos(w) + 4*cos(2*w);
figure; plot(w/pi,abs(X_check));
```

DTFT function:

```
function X = dtft(n,x,k)
% DESCRIPTION
%  Performs an approximate Discrete Time Fourier Transform 
%  the approximation is due to the fact that the output is 
%  not continous. ex. X = dtft(n,x,k); 
%  
% NOTE : Only for finite duration signals.
%
% INPUT VARIABLES
%  n = number of samples 
%  x = array containing time domain signal samples
%  k = evenly spaced divisions of omega (frequency)
%
% OUTPUT VARIABLES
%  X = the transformed output
%  Various graphs of signal aspects
%
% REFERENCES
%  Adapted from "Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB 3rd ed." - Ingle, V.,
%  Proakis, J. (pg. 65). 
%
% DOCUMENTATION
%  ver 1.0 by Dominic Meads  5/8/2020
%  filename: dtft.m
%
% ENGINEER'S COMMENTS
%  The authors reccommend to use this more as an
%  excersize rather than a full function. As stated above, use the DFT for
%  better results.
%

kmax = length(k)-1;

w = (pi/kmax)*k;  % calculates the evenly spaced frequencies 
X = x * (exp(-j*pi/kmax)) .^(n'*k); % calculates the DTFT
end
```

Comment: Maybe this will help:

$$ X(e^{j\omega}) = 3 + 2 \frac{e^{j\omega}+e^{-j\omega}}{2} + 4\frac{e^{j2\omega}+e^{-j2\omega}}{2}
= 2 e^{-j2\omega}  + e^{-j\omega} + 3 + e^{j\omega} +2 e^{j2\omega}$$

Comment: Hi Cedron, Yes that helps a lot. I now have the sequence x[n] = [2 1 3 1 2], with -2 <= n <= 2, mut its still not the same when I check the dtft of that sequence with with original. Am I missing someting?

Comment: I don't use MATLAB and I don't care for its syntax.  If the code above is what you are talking about, you are way off.  This is not something you test numerically.  Plug your sequence back into the definition and apply Euler's equation:

$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos( \theta ) + i \cdot \sin( \theta ) $$

If you want to understand that better, I recommend my first blog article, and one of my later ones.

https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php, https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1238.php